# Where is the input value saved in a TreeEditor?

Tags: extjs, treeview, tree, treepanel

I'm trying to implement an ExtJS TreeEditor, but whenever I edit a leaf the value changes on the display, but I can't figure out where the new input value is saved in the ExtJS object.

I've traced the documentation, and am using Firebug, but cannot find the new values for the life of me.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The TreeEditor updates the text attribute of the edited node.

You can also access the new value by listening to the 'complete' event on the TreeEditor.